# Get list of multiple image url firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Below is my code to upload multiple images to firebase storage.

```
fileToUpload.putFile(fileUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) { throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()); }
        return fileToUpload.getDownloadUrl(); }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            fileDoneList.remove(finalI);
            fileDoneList.add(finalI, "done");
            uploadListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            post.child(id).setValue(new Model_Post(id,editText.getText().toString(),
                    hours,minutes,days,months,years,task.getResult().toString(),
                    String.valueOf(totalItemsSelected),
                    ref_id,firebaseUser.getUid()));

            p.dismiss(); onBackPressed();
            toast_success("Upload post with pictures succeed");

        }
        else { show_error(); }
    }
});
```

With this code, upload multiple images success but when comes to get all the image url, it's failed. `task.getResult().toString()` only show the last image url. If I upload 5 images at the same time, only can get the 5th image url. How to get list of image url's and upload it into Firebase Database?

Comment: The code you shared only shows the uploading of a single file. It's hard to say what's going on to make it fail with multiple files. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since that is the best way to ask for help with code related problems.

Comment: Yeah thats why I'm asking about the code. How to get multiple image url's. Maybe you can give me an idea. The code may be wrong and I get it. Btw, the code that I shared uploading of a single file **with multiple images**. I want to get the url of images

Comment: Do you mean you're uploading a zip file with multiple images in it? There's no way to access the individual images in that case. Each file you upload gets a single download URL. Cloud Storage does not unpack a zip file for you. If you want to access the separate files, you will need to upload them individually.